# showing the inverse of an element is a generator of the non-inverse

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> Question:
>   Let $G$ be a group and let $a \in G$.
>
> Prove that $\left \langle a^{-1} \right \rangle=\left \langle a \right \rangle$

Suppose $\left \langle a^{-1} \right \rangle$ so $\left \langle a^{-1} \right \rangle=\left \{ a^{0},a^{-1},a^{-2},a^{-3},\cdot \cdot \cdot  \right \}$

But $a \in G$ so by the inverse property $a^{-1} \in G \,\, \forall \, \, a \in G$

Thus,

$\left \langle a^{-1} \right \rangle=\left \{ \left ( a^{-1} \right )^{0},\left ( a^{-1} \right )^{-1},\left ( a^{-1} \right )^{-2},\left ( a^{-1} \right )^{-3},\cdot \cdot \cdot  \right \}
=\left \{ a^{0},a^{1},a^{2},a^{3},\cdot \cdot \cdot  \right \}
=\left \langle a \right \rangle$

as required

> Note:$a^{0}=e$

Is my proof valid? Thanks in advance.

Comment: By definition, for $G$ a group and $g\in G$, you have $$\langle g \rangle = \{\ldots,g^{-2},g^{-1},g^0,g^1,g^2,\ldots\rangle,$$ not $$\langle g \rangle = \{g^0,g^1,g^2,\ldots\}.$$

Comment: The phrase "Suppose $\langle a^{-1}\rangle$" doesn't make sense.  You can only suppose a fact is true, but there is no verb in what you wrote.  Perhaps you meant consider?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes, that's it. Thanks for pointing that out. It did felt odd.